# JQuery - Checkbox on-change event doesn't fire if checked using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this `Check All` function which check all check boxes. I use JQuery to do that.

But I also have this `on change` function that toggle a class to the wrapper div:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

That function runs when I click the Checkbox, but not if I click `Check all`.

Is there any way to manually fire an event using JQuery? Or is there better solution?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here's the simplified HTML:

```
<a id="check_all">Check All</a>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="abc">ABC<br>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="pqr">PQR<br>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="xyz">XYZ<br>
</div>
```

**Here's the JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/DarcFiddle/d4VTh/

Comment: u can use trigger or u can post more of ur code here so i/we can help you more.

Comment: How do you know that the function did not run? Have you checked with the debugger?

Comment: @Andrei I have checked using `console.log()` and it only run when I directly click the checkbox. @all Wait, I will create the JSFiddle

Comment: @BeNdErR I have added the JSFiddle. Sorry

Answer (score 52, accepted):

After click check all you should call change() event like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
    });

    $("#check_all").on('click', function(){
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true).change();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I rewrite the code to simplify it. It doesn't have syntax error in real one.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I mean. You can check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DarcFiddle/d4VTh/2/) I have just created

Comment: PERFECT! With just a one word it works! Thank you very much good sir!

Comment: Alternatively you can do 

`$("input[type='checkbox']").click();`

which will also unselect your checkboxes (whereas this answer keeps them checked but unhighlights them.)

Answer (score 3):

This will trigger the `change` event, but only after you bind it first.

```
$('input[type="checkbox]').trigger('change');
```

Comment: I'm quite newb at JQuery, so I'm not sure what is binding. I will take a look later. But for this time, visnu's answer works fine.

Comment: @DarcCode, when you use `.on()`, you're binding or attaching an event to an element

Comment: So since I use `on()`, does it mean that my code is already binded?

Comment: @DarcCode Exactly, but you can only use the `trigger` after it's binded, otherwise it won't trigger anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox]' ,function(){
     // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox
      var $this = $(this);   
    if ($this.is(':checked')){//To CHECK CHECK BOX IS CHECKED OR NOT
         $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

Hope It Helps,

Comment: Thank you for your time, but his one doesn't work. You can check visnu's answer for the perfect one.

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical to visnu's answer, but directly calling click() will fire all the click events bound by jQuery.  If you demo this, you will see it also unchecks the boxes, whereas his answer simply removes the highlight while they remain clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
    });

    $("#check_all").on('click', function(){
        $("input[type='checkbox']").click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle modification of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/d4VTh/51/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
        if (this.checked)
            $(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight');
        else 
            $(this).closest('div').removeClass('highlight');
    });

    $("#check_all").on('click', function(){
        var item = $("input[type='checkbox']")
        item.prop('checked', !item.prop('checked')).change();
    });
});
```