# Check my radio button by code and also trigger change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check my radio button manually like below. But the problem is that the event is not fired (when checked manually).

```
$(function () {
    // always check the 1st element
    $("input:radio[name=MatrixID]:first").attr('checked', true).click();
});

$('.editor-field > input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    // !!! not fired when checked by code!!??
    p.mustSave = true;
});
```

**My question: how to check manually (by code) my radio button and also trigger change event?**

My html:

```
            <p>
                <span class="editor-field">
                    <input name="MatrixID" id="MatrixID873" type="radio" checked="checked" value="873"/>
                </span>
            </p>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post your HTML too please. And a jsFiddle while you're at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - Checkbox on-change event doesn't fire if checked using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892382/jquery-checkbox-on-change-event-doesnt-fire-if-checked-using-jquery)

Comment: don't use `attr()` for properties...use `prop()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.click()` trigger click event, but you are using `change()`. Try this instead :

```
$("input:radio[name=MatrixID]:first").prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I just tried as you suggested. My radio button is selected, that's ok but the change event is still not triggered??

Comment: @Bronzato Please check your code again, it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fpN86/

Comment: @Bronzato any error in console? The problem may be somewhere else becaause it should work :)

Comment: I think my problem is that I have the code event for the change managed inside another javascript file and this one is loaded after my radio button checked. Difficult to explain. I need to check (by code) only after all other script is loaded...

Comment: @Bronzato shouldnt matter since you code that check the input is inside a DOM ready handler. But to be sure, you could move it inside a `$(window).load(function(){})`

Comment: @Karl-André I didn't reload all my page each time, my navigation is done by loading script & html from ajax calls so the `$(window).load` is only loaded at the very beginning. So it don't work this way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato if you content is loaded dynamicly, `$('.editor-field > input[type=radio]').change(function () {})` should be `$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name=MatrixID]:first', function(){})` on the main JS file. That may be the only problem, the trigger event is fired but there is no event binded on the input.